# How to connect GeoJSON LineString coordinates with a shortest distance

Tags: geojson, linestring

I have the following GeoJSON `LineString` that I generate from some data (that I don't own). The problem is that when this line is rendered, the 2nd coordinate (with a positive longitude) of the line is connected to the 3rd coordinate (with a negative longitude) by making a line that crosses the entire globe instead of taking the shortest distance.

Is my GeoJSON wrong?

[image]

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ident": "R336",
                "type": "high"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        168.783111111111,
                        48.6756666666667
                    ],
                    [
                        175.945333333333,
                        50.5152222222222
                    ],
                    [
                        -176.674275,
                        51.871075
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's more a defect in the plotting application, but you might want to make it a multi-part line, with a split along the 175.945,-176.674 delta, at 180/-180.  Either that, or let the -176.674 roll over to 183.326.

Comment: it looks like most of the plotting application have this behaviour. e.g. https://labs.mapbox.com/labs/mbxdataexplorer/ https://geojson.io/ or QGIS. The `MultiLineString` seems to produce the same result